# Twitter-Bootstrap Menu Not Working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, joomla

I am trying to write a custom template for the first time in Joomla 3.0 using Twitter-Bootstrap.

[edit]removed link to site[/edit]

Nothing I do is making the template's menu work. Front page only. Forget the inside pages, please.

I think it's due to the fact that the template can't seem to access the javascript's files.

Any advice would be very much appreciated in getting the template's menu working when the window is resized.

I've tried using this:

```
    <?php
    defined('_JEXEC') or die;
    $doc = JFactory::getDocument();
    $doc->addScript('/templates/' . $this->template . '/js/main.js', 'text/javascript');
    $doc->addScript('/templates/' . $this->template . '/js/jquery.js', 'text/javascript');
    $doc->addScript('/templates/' . $this->template . '/js/bootstrap-transition.js',   'text/javascript');
    $doc->addScript('/templates/' . $this->template . '/js/bootstrap-alert.js', 'text/javascript');
    $doc->addScript('/templates/' . $this->template . '/js/bootstrap-modal.js', 'text/javascript');
    $doc->addScript('/templates/' . $this->template . '/js/bootstrap-dropdown.js', 'text/javascript');
    $doc->addScript('/templates/' . $this->template . '/js/bootstrap-scrollspy.js', 'text/javascript');
    $doc->addScript('/templates/' . $this->template . '/js/bootstrap-tab.js', 'text/javascript');
    $doc->addScript('/templates/' . $this->template . '/js/bootstrap-tooltip.js', 'text/javascript');
    $doc->addScript('/templates/' . $this->template . '/js/bootstrap-popover.js', 'text/javascript');
    $doc->addScript('/templates/' . $this->template . '/js/bootstrap-button.js', 'text/javascript');
    $doc->addScript('/templates/' . $this->template . '/js/bootstrap-collapse.js', 'text/javascript');
    $doc->addScript('/templates/' . $this->template . '/js/bootstrap-carousel.js', 'text/javascript');
    $doc->addScript('/templates/' . $this->template . '/js/bootstrap-typeahead.js', 'text/javascript');
    ?>
```

And I've tried this:

```
<link href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/js/jquery.js" />
<link href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/js/bootstrap-transition.js" />
<link href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/js/bootstrap-alert.js" />
<link href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/js/bootstrap-modal.js" />
<link href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/js/bootstrap-dropdown.js" />
<link href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/js/bootstrap-scrollspy.js" />
<link href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/js/bootstrap-tab.js" />
<link href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/js/bootstrap-tooltip.js" />
<link href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/js/bootstrap-popover.js" />
<link href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/js/bootstrap-button.js" />
<link href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/js/bootstrap-collapse.js" />
<link href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/js/bootstrap-carousel.js" />
<link href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/js/bootstrap-typeahead.js" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an error, which you can see in chrome/firefox console

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
```

You probably did not include jquery.

Moreover

```
<link href="....
```

is for CSS not for Javascript

Comment: i did include jQuery. look at the examples above. it's in both. the problem is that it's not reading the javascript files, i think. and I'm at loss at how to make it read it.

Comment: replace <link> with <script> tag for scripts, and it should work

Comment: as per your edit, ok, it's for css. look at the first example, then. that's for javascript, i think. and that's not working either. what is the right way to have javascripts files included the right way so the template will read it?

Comment: do you mean like this:  <script href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/js/jquery.js" /></script>

Comment: It is probably problem with the path. Try to print this path to the source and check if it is correct. About your previous comment: yes try this way

Comment: @Garath i tried with script tag ... it still doesn't work. Clearly, it's a path problem. Which is what I've been saying all along. But if you look at the view source, and click on the javascript files, you can read it, which means it's the right path, right? Otherwise, you shouldn't be able to read the files if the path is wrong, yes?

Comment: @davidkonrad, dude, i'm sorry if you're having a bad day or whatever, but please keep your rants out of my questions. i asked a question. i gave two ways of trying to make it work. i'm not asking for someone to write my template. just help me to figure out why it's not reading the javascript files. and people are always trying to learn. no need to rain on their parade because you are apparently the awesome. sorry, normally not this snarky online ever but i'm frustrated that my javscript files aren't being read, and i don't need your crap to make me feel worse. ok? thanks.

Comment: script tag should be: <script src="/templates/test16/js/jquery.js"></script> not <script href="/templates/test16/js/jquery.js" /></script>

Comment: @Garath, thank you so much. Much appreciated. Your last comment worked. Can't believe that it was just due to a tiny detail that i should have paid more attention to. Thank you again.

Comment: @oy vey, sorry, you are absolutely right - has deleted the stupid comment.

Comment: @davidkonrad - no worries. now that my js files are being read, i'm all happy. =) anyway, i get it ... but we're all in the same boat basically. and that's one of the reason why i love stack overflow so much ... is that i feel i'm able to ask questions here almost always. not always, mind you. =) b/c sometimes i'm too shy to ask question that i feel i should have understood already. and really, the only person that's being affected at the end of the day is me if i don't ask my questions. so ... shrugs. hope the rest of your day is better. =)

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as you're using Joomla 3.0, the best way to load the Bootstrap framework would be as follows:

```
JHtml::_('bootstrap.framework');
```

It uses less lines of code, uses the Joomla 3.0 coding standards and it ensures jQuery is loaded on **noConflict** mode.

Comment: Do you mean like this: <?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die;
JHtml::_('bootstrap.framework');
?>

Comment: @oyvey - yes. best place to add it would be the index.php in the template folder ;)

Comment: And I don't need to include the jquery file at all? Or it just makes sure that any jquery files i have in template won't be in conflict?

Comment: i see! that means my jquery file inclusion is redundant! what else does it mean by including that statement? hope you don't mind me asking.

Comment: I basically loads the Bootstrap framework (all the files) and the jQuery framework which saves you having to import each one indivudually. It also loads jQuery in noConflict mode so that is doesn't conflict with other libraries or extensions, by replacing `$.` with `jQuery.`

Comment: hmm that's odd. I'm referring to the file you tried to include in your question

Comment: nvm my previous question. just googled it, and found this page: http://docs.joomla.org/J3.0:Javascript_Frameworks. the interesting thing is that to load jQuery, use this: JHtml::_('jquery.framework');. but when i tried that, and removed my jquery file inclusion, it still didn't work. hm. oh well, will look into it later.

Comment: have you ensured that **bootstrap.js** and **bootstrap.min.js** are in the following folder: **root/media/jui/js** ?